Behavior of a single emitted photon
Suppose you have a transmitter sending out a single photon. If you think about this photon as a wave, you will see a circular wave moving away from the transmitter. Over millennia, this wave spreads throughout the galaxy. Now, if detectors are placed all over the galaxy and the photon is eventually detected by one of them, does the wave instantaneously vanish in all other regions of the galaxy?

That's a model that works.

or maybe the photon already has a preferred direction from the EM field

It's an excellent question so I don't know why it got a downvote. However it has been asked before - see my link.

What are photons, EM radiation and EM waves
